# How to change color of past event in calendar use Vuetifyjs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vcalendar

I would like to change the color of background the past events in calendar of vuetifyjs. Type of calendar is day. I guess I need to add a class to them but that is the problem, how I do that?

Comment: could you add more context ? like some code, and what did you try already ?

Comment: I used vuetify component at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/